# Logging into an AWS instance with a non-root user

Tags: login, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

It seems from the  EC2 documentation that one must logon with the specific userid associated with the AMI:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

> Use the ssh command to connect to the instance. You'll specify the
>   private key (.pem) file and user_name@public_dns_name. For Amazon
>   Linux, the user name is ec2-user. For RHEL5, the user name is either
>   root or ec2-user. For Ubuntu, the user name is ubuntu. For Fedora, the
>   user name is either fedora or ec2-user. For SUSE Linux, the user name
>   is root. Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with your
>   AMI provider.

```
ssh -i my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Now I have tried to logon with a different user - that was created via *adduser*:

```
adduser changsha
```

That user works on the system:

```
root@ip-10-151-25-94 ~]$ su - changsha
[changsha@ip-10-151-25-94 ~]$
```

However it is not (apparently) possible to logon to the AWS instance using that id.   Notice: *no "Enter Password" is returned*.  It just fails straightaway.

```
13:36:28/sparkup2 $ssh -i ~/.ssh/hwspark14.pem changsha@ec2-54-83-81-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The only thing working presently is to logon with root!  So then - how do we manage multiple users on the cluster?

**Update** David's answer works: here is some additional info

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=138588

```
You should find an authorized_keys file (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, this might change with other distros, I guess).
Let's check what it is:
$ cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
Outuput:
ssh-rsa SAGsg43 (....) sd53ySGS aws_machines

And that is the corresponding public key.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `.ssh` directory under the home directory of the new user and copy your public key there. Make sure you also set the proper permissions for the `authorized_keys` file. Detailed instructions can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html).

Comment: Thx for the pointer.  I only have the private key foo.**pem**  . AWS changed their handling of key pairs couple years back: where is the public key now?

Comment: You can copy it from the `.ssh` directory of the `ec2-user` if you want to use the same key. Otherwise you can generate a private/public key pair locally and use that instead. It doesn't have to come from AWS.

Comment: Got it : an old aws post gives more details : I am updating the OP.